# How to simulate from poisson distribution using simulations from exponential distribution

Tags: r, simulation, poisson

I am asked to implement an algorithm to simulate from a poisson (lambda) distribution using simulation from an exponential distribution.

I was given the following density:
P(X = k) = P(X1 + · · · + Xk ≤ 1 < X1 + · · · + Xk+1), for k = 1, 2, . . . .
P(X = k) is the poisson with lambda, and Xi is exponential distribution.

I wrote code to simulate the exponential distribution, but have no clue how to simulate a poisson. Could anybody help me about this? Thanks million.

My code:

```
n<-c(1:k)
  u<-runif(k)
  x<--log(1-u)/lambda
```

Comment: use `rpois` function for random generation for the Poisson distribution with parameter lambda.

Answer (score 6):

I'm working on the assumption you (or your instructor) want to do this from first principles rather than just calling the builtin Poisson generator.  The algorithm is pretty straightforward. You count how many exponentials you can generate with the specified rate until their sum exceeds 1.

My R is rusty and this sounds like a homework anyway, so I'll express it as pseudo-code:

```
count <- 0
sum <- 0
repeat {
  generate x ~ exp(lambda)
  sum <- sum + x
  if sum > 1
    break
  else
    count <- count + 1
}
```

The value of `count` after you `break` from the loop is your Poisson outcome for this trial.  If you wrap this as a function, return `count` rather than `break`ing from the loop.

You can improve this computationally in a couple of ways.  The first is to notice that the `1-U` term for generating the exponentials has a uniform distribution, and can be replaced by just `U`.  The more significant improvement is obtained by writing the evaluation as maximize `i` s.t. `SUM(-log(Ui) / rate) <= 1`, so `SUM(log(Ui)) >= -rate`.

Now exponentiate both sides and simplify to get

```
PRODUCT(Ui) >= Exp(-rate).
```

The right-hand side of this is constant, and can be pre-calculated, reducing the amount of work from `k+1` log evaluations and additions to one exponentiation and `k+1` multiplications:

```
count <- 0
product <- 1
threshold = Exp(-lambda)
repeat {
  generate u ~ Uniform(0,1)
  product <- product * u
  if product < threshold
    break
  else
    count <- count + 1
}
```

Assuming you do the `U` for `1-U` substitution for both implementations, they are algebraically equal and will yield identical answers to within the precision of floating point arithmetic for a given set of `U`'s.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rpois` to generate Poisson variates as per above suggestion. However, my understanding of the question is that you wish to do so from first principles rather than using built-in functions. To do this, you need to use the property of the Poisson arrivals stating that the inter-arrival times are exponentially distributed. Therefore we proceed as follows:

**Step 1:** Generate a (large) sample from the exponential distribution and create vector of cumulative sums. The k-th entry of this vector is the waiting time to the k-th Poisson arrival

**Step 2:** Measure how many arrivals we see in a unit time interval

**Step3:** Repeat steps 1 and 2 many times and gather the results into a vector

This will be your sample from the Poisson distribution with the correct rate parameter.

The code:

```
lambda=20 # for example
out=sapply(1:100000, function(i){
   u<-runif(100)
   x<--log(1-u)/lambda
   y=cumsum(x)
   length(which(y<=1))
})
```

Then you can test the validity vs the built-in function via the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:

```
ks.test(out, rpois(100000, lambda))
```